# C# LINQ DataTime List

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, list, datetime

Have a some problem with converting to List

```
public List<DateTime> findDateBetween(DateTime start,DateTime end)
{
    var query = from entry in sd.gw_chemistry
                where (entry.insert_datetime >=start & entry.insert_datetime<=end & a == entry.well_id & b == entry.indicator_id)
                select entry.insert_datetime;
    return (List<DateTime>)query;
}`
```

> Error:
>   System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type "System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]]" to type  "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]".

Comment: Are those really &s and not &&s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your code.

- Your query is selecting elements of type `DateTime?` (or `Nullable<DateTime>`). You will need to decide what you want to do if a date is `null`. Exclude it from the results? Return a default value? If you can be sure it will never be `null`, you can `select entry.insert_datetime.Value`.
- Your query does not return a list, you will have to convert it to a list using `ToList()`.
- For the conditional AND operator (`&&`) it appears you are using `&`.
- You are using variables `a` and `b` that do not seem to be defined anywhere (unless they are member variables).

So assuming that `a` and `b` are member variables, and an `insert_datetime` is never `null` you can do:

```
return sd.gw_chemistry
   .Where(e =>
        e.insert_datetime >= start && e.insert_datetime <= end && 
        a == entry.well_id && b == entry.indicator_id)
   .Select(e => e.insert_datetime.Value)
   .ToList();
```

Comment: `&` is also a logical operator.

Answer (score 0):

As the error is trying to tell you, that isn't a `List<T>`, and you can't cast it to a type that it isn't.

You can create a `List<T>` from your query by calling `.ToList()`.

Comment: So, I changed my query on 
"...select entry.insert_datetime).ToList();
            return query"
But now have exception
"System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime?>"  to type "System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime>"

Comment: You need to use `.Value` to get the value of the nullable DateTime in the select clause.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing serious here. You just need to call `ToList()` on your `query`. However I do see the usage of `&` instead of `&&` as a serious problem.

Correct code should look like:

```
public List<DateTime> findDateBetween(DateTime start,DateTime end)
{
    var query = 
              from entry in sd.gw_chemistry
              where (entry.insert_datetime >=start && 
                     entry.insert_datetime<=end && 
                     a == entry.well_id && 
                     b == entry.indicator_id)
            select entry.insert_datetime.Value;
    return query.ToList();
}`
```

Comment: Nope, new problem "System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime?>" to type "System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime>"

Comment: @byvaet: Edited. Check new version. The problem is, we can't guess the structure of your data by looking at the piece of code you have provided. If `insert_datetime` is nullable, you should have already considered using `.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<DateTime> findDateBetween(DateTime start,DateTime end)
    {var query = from entry in sd.gw_chemistry
        where (entry.insert_datetime >=start & entry.insert_datetime<=end & a == entry.well_id & b == entry.indicator_id)
        select entry.insert_datetime;
        return query.ToList();}
```